# Duplicate keys while adding data to cache

Tags: c#, .net, azure, caching, azure-cloud-services

I'm using the following code to add data to my cache:

```
public void Add(string key, object item, int duration)
    {
        if (DataCacheHelper.DataCache.Get(key) == null)
        {
            if (duration > 0)
            {
                DataCacheHelper.DataCache.Add(key, item, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, duration));
            }
            else
            {
                DataCacheHelper.DataCache.Add(key, item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Update(key, item);
        }
    }
```

Notice how I have the 'if' statement before I add the data to either add it or update.

Still with this code I'm still getting the following error:
[image]

Does anyone know what I'm missing in all this?

The program is running on an Azure Cloud service with 2 instances. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can it be that DataCache.Get(string) returns NULL if the entry is in the cache but it is already expired?

Comment: Get is supposed to return null if the entry has expired. Perhaps this is a race condition?

Comment: Remember, `DataCacheHelper.DataCache.Put` solves cache usage issue but doesn't solve *thread concurrency* issue. Without solving that, your cache may be replaced several times when users start using your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [DataCache.Put](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff424927%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to add or replace the cached object:

> If the object is not present when this method is called, it will be
>   added to the cache. If the object is already present, it will be
>   replaced. ([src](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790944.aspx))

This is the resulting method:

```
public void Add(string key, object item, int duration)
{
    if (duration > 0)
    {
         DataCacheHelper.DataCache.Put(key, item, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, duration));
    }
    else
    {
         DataCacheHelper.DataCache.Put(key, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking this out as we speak and it seems most promising.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Add`, you need to sync your threads. Try to refactoring your code as follows

```
public void Add(string key, object item, int duration)
{

    lock(_myStaticLockObject) // Declare static lock object (new Object()) to use for preventing other threads to execute this code. 
    {
        if (DataCacheHelper.DataCache.Get(key) == null)
        {
            if (duration > 0)
            {
                DataCacheHelper.DataCache.Add(key, item, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, duration));
            }
            else
            {
                DataCacheHelper.DataCache.Add(key, item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Update(key, item);
        }
    }
}
```

This way only one thread at the time will try adding something to cache